# Need help to understand this .reorder_level

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, lodash

I'm trying to write tests using the mocha frameworks and have this function

```
this.checkReorder = function  () {
    var result = [];
    this.products.forEach(function (p) {
        if (p.quantity <= p.reorder_level) {
            result.push(p) ;
        }
    })
    return result ;
}
```

I don't understand the if statement

So if I have these products

```
cat.addProduct(new Product("Product 1", 100, 10.00, 10  ) );
cat.addProduct(new Product("Product 2", 100, 10.00, 10 ) );
cat.addProduct(new Product("Product 3", 100, 10.00, 10 ) );
```

When I use the .reorder_level what is the result from this?

Comment: What dont you understand? It looks like a pretty basic conditional check

Comment: You iterate over all products, making a temporary copy into `p` for each item. Then you check if the `quantity` of the current product `p` is under or the same as the `reorder_level` of the current product `p`.

Comment: what's there to understand, you have some object (p) with properties quantity and reorder_level. also this has nothing to do with lodash or mocha. it's vanilla js

Comment: Just  .reorder_level I get its looking for products quantity is less than or equal to it

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a page that had this explained, sorry about that.